# Understanding these Mosfet Data sheet Specs

Tags: powermosfet

So my local electronics store has a catalog of MOSFETS they sell.

I’m having a little trouble interpreting some of the specs.

In particular:

“gate to source cutoff voltage” Where it says 4V MAX, does that imply that 4V is the maximum VGS will take before problems? What is VTN? And can I turn it on with say 5V from an arduino output pin?

And “drain to source breakdown voltage” where it lists 100V MIN. Does this imply that 100V is the minimum VDS? Can I use lower voltage for the power supply? 10V for instance?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think “gate to source cutoff voltage” is the threshold voltage, below which the FET will not conduct to any appreciable extent.

Comment: I don't see VTN. Could you describe where it is on the chart?

Comment: Again, I could be wrong, but I think "drain to source cutoff voltage" is the voltage at which the device will conduct even when the gate to source voltage is 0. But I also don't see that on the datasheet, rather "drain to source breakdown voltage", which is what I just described.

Comment: @mathkeepamebusy It’s not on the chart unfortunately, or the box they come in which I will add a picture of

Comment: Here is the real datashseet. I typed NTE 2943 in a search engine and this was the first hit. https://www.nteinc.com/specs/2900to2999/pdf/nte2943.pdf. 4V is the threshold voltage aka Vgs(th). Rds(on) is only specified at Vgs = 10V, so driving them from a 5V arduino is probably not the best idea or plan. I am sure the other parts can be found also.

Comment: Yes unfortunately they did not have logic level MOSFET’s in stock at this store so I looked into what these power mosfets do. I will definitely be using different mosfets.

Comment: If you use NMOS for a power switch you either need to put it on the low side or drive it with a voltage considerably higher than the voltage you are switching. I apologize if you already know this. In my experience I have generally found it better to use high side PMOS for switching power to anciallary circuits. Trying to switch the low-side has many pitfalls and deprives you of the convenience of a common ground.

Answer (score 2):

NTE does not make parts. The buy normal parts, add their own number then raise the price.
Normal parts have a correct detailed datasheet, NTE parts do not.

You copied the words wrong. NTE says Breakdown Voltage but you said Cutoff Voltage that is completely different. The breakdown voltage is the voltage that they have breakdown (you do not want breakdown). It is a minimum voltage like 100V because some will breakdown with 100V, and some will breakdown with a little higher voltage like 110V or 120V.

A detailed datasheet will say the gate to source voltage that will turn on the Mosfet well. NTE does not say this important spec but the other things they say point to ordinary Mosfets that need 10V to turn on well.
Since you will drive the Mosfets with only 5V from an arduino you cannot use these ordinary Mosfets, you need Mosfets that the manufacturer says are "Logic Level".

Comment: _"NTE does not make parts. The buy normal parts, add their own number then raise the price."_- Interesting... can you provide a cite for that?

Comment: @BruceAbbott "NOTE: NTE DOES NOT supply data sheets on generic industry standard part numbers." ([from here](https://www.nteinc.com/linear_web/cmos.php)) is telling.

Comment: According to NTE's website that only applies to TTL and CMOS ICs. Many 'manufacturers' don't make their own chips. The question is where do NTE get theirs from. If the NTE 'equivalent' is actually the original, that is good news for those us who need an _identical_ replacement, especially for parts that are not otherwise available.

Answer (score 1):

You can find full specifications for some NTE transistors at NTE's website. If you want to use a transistor as a load switch, I would recommend using P-channel MOSFET as a high side switch. Select a part with a lower Vgs(th) of only a few volts. Preferably, it would have a specified and low Rds(on) at Vgs(th) of 5V or lower so you can be confident that you can turn it on fully with 5V from source to gate.

Here is one possible NTE part that should work as a high-side switch for 5V (NTE 2919):
https://www.nteinc.com/specs/2900to2999/pdf/nte2919.pdf

Here is the NTE website where you can see datasheets for their MOSFETS if you click in the right place. Some of them use the same terminology as that table. Some of them use more industry standard terminology (such as Vgs(th) and Rds(on)).

https://www.nteinc.com/fets/mosfets.php

Answer (score 0):

That’s rather sparse information compared to what you’d expect from a proper datasheet, but better then nothing.  The cutoff voltage is the gate voltage at which no significant current will flow into the source.  However, the FET isn’t saturated (fully conducting) until the gate is well above this voltage, so 5V may not give you the drain-source current you desire.  The drain to source breakdown voltage is the absolute maximum operating voltage, using a 100V device at 10V is fine.

Comment: I’m looking to use mosfets as switches to supply more power for my arduino projects. I don’t have a calculator at the moment, but could 5V put it into triode for switching operation?

Comment: Do you mean a triac?  A triode is an old-fashioned valve or vacuum tube.

Comment: @Frog Linear mode in MOSFETs is sometimes called triode mode.

Comment: You live and learn :-) @strugglingstudent117 5V on the gate will make the FET conduct to some degree but it’s impossible to say how much without a proper datasheet.  Perhaps just give it a try.

Comment: I’ll concur. My university in the US teaches use of the term “triode operation”. Which goes back to those nostalgic vacuum tube days.

Comment: When I was learning about FETs, triodes were still in fairly common use so it would have been very confusing :-)